# Estimating new columns with n-1 cases in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to build a code for a fund analysis, which starts from the returns of the fund at different frequencies. I have been able to split the data by frequencies, that is, daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly, but the next step is not quite working for me. I have done it many times on excel and SPSS, but since R is a new language for me, it is proving to be challenging. A sample of my data is given herewith :

```
    Date         Dat1            Dat2    
 30/06/2009     54.26          1307.16    
 31/07/2009     65.28          1425.40    
 31/08/2009     70.71          1498.97    
 30/09/2009     76.18          1552.84    
 30/10/2009     71.92          1532.74    
 30/11/2009     77.14          1559.57
```

What I wish to do is to have two more columns, with n-1 elements in them, starting at the second index. So the entries in the new columns for the 30/06/2009 would be '-' and '-' and for the 31/07/2009 row would be the values of (65.28-54.26)/54.26 and (1425.40-1307.16)/1307.16 and so forth, until the very last case. But when I run the simple code
`Daily$Dat1.Return <- diff(log(Daily$Dat1))` I get the following error :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Dat1, value = c(-0.0616981144702153,  : 
  replacement has 2161 rows, data has 2162
```

How can I get the columns I want?

Comment: try `Daily$Dat1.Return<- c("-",diff(log(Daily$Dat1)))`

Comment: It works! Let me see if I get this. c concatenated the - with my resultant array?

Comment: yes - because you are taking the difference, the new vector has `n-1` length. You then manually add `-` to the first case, in which a difference is not taken. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, @boski, for the help! It worked. If I may ask one more follow-up question, I tried adding another column named multiple, with the command     'Daily$Multiple <- Daily$Dat1.Return/Daily$Dat2.Return)'    , but it gives me the error 'non-numeric argument to binary operator', presumably because of the first entry of "-". How do I rectify this?

Comment: I got it. When I was concatenating with "-", R was converting my numbers to string characters, hence the error. But once I use as.numeric(), the problem is solved:-)